# Installing rJava on centos (64 bit). Could not find lpcre, llzma

Tags: r, linux, centos, rjava

I am trying to install rJava on centos7 (64bit). I am getting the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to install the following for `llzma`

Package `xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64` already installed and latest version.
Package `lzma-sdk457-4.57-12.el7.x86_64` already installed and latest version.

It did not help

For `lpcre` I did not find any solution.

Comment: Try `yum install pcre` and `yum install xz-libs`.

Comment: I already have "Package pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version" and "Package xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version" It did not help.

Comment: But ... where did you have them installed?

Comment: yum install. The output is from yum install. `"Package pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version" and "Package xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version" `

Answer (score 1):

folks from rflow suggested to install the devel packages. Following worked.

```
sudo yum install pcre pcre-devel xz xz-devel
```